# Can someone tell me how to make the motion from top to bottom of the scroller of this jquery plugin?http://plugins.jquery.com/project/vTicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-animate

Can someone tell me how to make the motion from top to bottom of the scroller of this jquery plugin?http://plugins.jquery.com/project/vTicker.

i want the newest child to display at the top.Simply changing the

```
obj.animate({top: '+=' + height + 'px'}
```

to

```
obj.animate({top: '-=' + height + 'px'}
```

changes the direction but does not displat the newest child on the top

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest version of plugin, because there was added this feature to choose a direction.